# copyQ global shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, clipboard-manager

I am using copyQ as the clipboard manager and it works fine with all other environment EXCEPT, when I am writing in Gummi (A Latex editor), it doesn't work according to its `show/hide window` keyboard-shortcut.
I wish to summon copyQ with key-shortcut from Gummi as well.
Can someone kindly provide me a remedy?

Is there an option that CopyQ doesn't close after minimizing, since even window-change closes copyq-main-window. What's possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using CopyQ for a while and it works seamlessly across all the applications. I haven't used Gummi but I will suggest a solution for it.

### Custom shortcut

Instead of setting the shortcut in the application, set the shortcut in the Custom shortcut option in the Keyboard settings. Add the command as `copyq show` and add your custom shortcut to it. Now the clipboard will be shown when you use the shortcut. Remember, you have to clear the shortcut if the system is already using it.

[image: custom-shortcuts]

### Closing when Unfocussed

Your second concern was the CopyQ application closing when you switched to another window. You can change that by going to ***CopyQ preferences -> General -> Close When Unfocused***. Uncheck the option and you will be able to keep the window open even when you switch to another window.

[image: copyq-preferences]